# Challenges maintaining file consistency while copy & move file operations with FlushFileBuffer()

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-handling

We are using following steps to Copy, Move File:

1. Use system provided  function to `CopyFile()`, `MoveFile()`
2. open file using

   ```
   hFile = CreateFile(
                       FilePath,
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                       NULL
                       );
   ```
3. use `FlushFileBuffers(hfile)` to flush cache to disk.

Step 2 & 3 added because we face file corruption issues because windows functions `CopyFile()`, `MoveFile()` uses system cache and it introduced delay in file writing on physical device.

After using `FlushFileBuffers()` we somehow minimize number of file corruptions occurrences.
But there are few others like:

- File created with size 0 bytes
- File contains some junk data but file size is expected
- File contains only zeros with expected file size

So I would require help to find out whether the flow I am following is correct or I should consider other alternative to make sure file consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Transactional File System (TxF) feature of Windows, which will provide you with the consistency and atomicity you require. You'll need to use the transactional file I/O WIN32API methods instead of the normal ones.

Otherwise, you'll need to take care of consistency on your own.

Comment: Transactional NTFS is deprecated :(

Comment: Not exactly. It works in Windows 10/Server 2016. Microsoft recommends not to use it because they consider deprecating it some time in the future, but the feature works and isn't really obsolete.

Comment: It's not yet removed, but it is deprecated (which means they've announced it may be removed in the future)

Comment: OK then. Still usable, if you are willing to make a bet :-)